# NLP - why is "not" a stop word?

Tags: nlp, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words before performing topic modeling. I noticed that some negation words (not, nor, never, none etc..) are usually considered to be stop words. For example, NLTK, spacy and sklearn include "not" on their stop word lists. However, if we remove "not" from these sentences below they lose the significant meaning and that would not be accurate for topic modeling or sentiment analysis.

```
1). StackOverflow is helpful      => StackOverflow helpful
2). StackOverflow is not helpful  => StackOverflow helpful
```

Can anyone please explain why these negation words are typically considered to be stop words?

Comment: This question feels like it would get better answers on a more specialised site, as it's about the theory behind the software, rather than how to program with it. Maybe http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been manually migrated to a different Stack Exchange: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15765/nlp-why-is-not-a-stop-word

Comment: Yes agree, just could not close it by myself... So answered my own question and tried resolve it. But I cannot until tomorrow

Comment: Yeah, hope the comment didn't come across as abrupt, it's auto-generated when you use the vote-to-close system.

Answer (score 0):

Per [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop)'s advice above, please reference https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15765/nlp-why-is-not-a-stop-word for the answer.